Dice roll, expected sum of rolls until we get $3$?
We keep throwing a fair $6$-sided dice until we see $3$. What is the expected sum of all the dice rolls, including the last one? Note: please include the last roll in the sum as well.
The answer is simple in that it is simply $21$. But interestingly, no matter what number you specify in the problem statement (namely the expected number of sum until we see $x$, for $x \in [1,6]$ is all the same for all $x$), the answer is always $21$.
Now, this is mathematically provable. What would be the intuition behind this interesting phenomenon?

Is it not just that you $expect$ to see each outcome once in 6 rolls, and the sum of the outcomes is 21?

@RedFive my intuition would say that the expected sum is lower for a $1$ than a $6$ because the last roll is lower.  Clearly what is happening is the average roll that isn't a $1$ is higher than the average roll that isn't a $6$ to compensate.  Like so many of these problems we need a careful calculation to give the proper result.

Yes, but because you are including the last roll in the sum, it will not matter.

The expected number of throws is $6$ and the expected value of a throw is $3.5$, hence $21$.

The geometric distribution tells us that we expect to have five rolls before the $x$ shows up.
Suppose $x=6$. For the first five rolls, we "expect" to get a uniform spread of rolls $1,2,3,4,5$. So the expected sum of the six rolls is $(1+2+3+4+5)+6=21$.
Suppose $x=1$. For the first five rolls, we "expect" to get a uniform spread of rolls $2,3,4,5,6$. So the expected sum of the six rolls is $(2+3+4+5+6)+1=21$.
The sum of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is the same no matter which roll comes last. So it doesn't matter what the last roll is.

Using linearity of expectation:

The number of times you see a target number $t$ is $1$ (you stop when you first see it) and this adds $t$ to the sum

The expected number of times you see each non-target number $n$ before the target number $t$ is $1$ (it has a geometric distribution with parameter $\frac12$ as $n$ and $t$ are equally likely to appear on each roll) and this adds an expected $n$ to the sum

The expected sum is the sum of all these, i.e. $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$.



Alternatively, if the target number is $t$:

The non-$t$ rolls have expectation $\frac{21-t}{5}$ since each non-$t$ value is equally likely

You expect $5$ non-$t$ rolls followed by a $t$ roll, at which point you stop $\big($a geometric distribution with parameter $\frac16\big)$

So the expectation of the sum is $$5 \times \frac{21-t}{5}+1\times t=21.$$



Just to add another method, we can work recursively.  Say the target is $t$.
Consider the first toss, if it is a $t$, you are done and the answer is $t$.  Otherwise you add the toss to your score and the expectation from that point on is the same as it was at the start.  That is, $$E=\frac 16\times \left(t+\left(\sum_{i=1}^6 i\right) -t\right)+\frac 56 E\implies E=21$$
